# What is the interface to which nspawn binds by default?

Tags: networking, systemd, container, systemd-nspawn

I have a container created via `debootstrap` and it has network connectivity when started as

```
systemd-nspawn -D thecontainerdir -b
```

I have several network interfaces and would like it to bind to one of them. **How to tell systemd-nspawn to bid to a specific NIC?**

Please note that I am not asking about the [usage of the various private network switches](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-nspawn.html#--private-network) (`--network-macvlan`, `--network-macvlan`, ...) -- these will create a private network in my container which is then connected to a bridge or interface. I do not want to create a private network - the networking on a bare `nspawn` call is fine, I just want the container to bind to a specific NIC.